# Access project version within elixir application

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

I have an elixir project with a defined version. How can I access this from within the running application.

in mix.exs

```
  def project do
    [app: :my_app,
     version: "0.0.1"]
  end
```

I would like to be access this version number in the application so I can add it to the returned message. I looking for something in the env hash like the following

```
__ENV__.version
# => 0.0.1
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's a similar approach to retrieve the version string. It also relies on the `:application` module, but is maybe a bit more straightforward:

```
{:ok, vsn} = :application.get_key(:my_app, :vsn)
List.to_string(vsn)
```

Comment: This is a better way.  Personally, I'd still use the `charlist |> string |> integer` parsing pipeline, but this is definitely cleaner than using `which_applications`.

Comment: Yes good point. Chris' solution is obviously longer because it does an extra step to convert the string into a tuple of integers. Just for printing, the plain string should however be enough. You could combine the two answers to get the tuple if you need it.

Comment: If you're using escript or similar to build a cli app, this solution fits very well :)

Answer (score 40):

`Mix.Project` itself provides access to all project keywords defined in `mix.exs` using its `config/0` ([api doc](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/mix/Mix.Project.html#config/0)) function. For concise access it might be wrapped into a function:

```ruby
@version Mix.Project.config[:version]
def version(), do: @version
```

Comment: Make sure this is evaluated at compile time like shown in the example. Otherwise it will not work in production because `module Mix.Project is not available`.

Answer (score 22):

In recent versions of Elixir, the Application module now wraps this for you:

https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/application.ex

`Application.spec(:my_app, :vsn) |> to_string()`

The `Kernel.to_string()` method is necessary as `Application.spec/2` for the keys `:vsn` and `:description` return charlists. `to_string()` from the [Kernel](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html) module converts them to a binary.

Answer (score 6):

I found the version inside of `:application.which_applications`, but it requires some parsing:

```
defmodule AppHelper do
  @spec app_version(atom) :: {integer, integer, integer}
  def app_version(target_app) do
    :application.which_applications
    |> Enum.filter(fn({app, _, _}) ->
                    app == target_app
                   end)
    |> get_app_vsn
  end

  # I use a sensible fallback when we can't find the app,
  # you could omit the first signature and just crash when the app DNE.
  defp get_app_vsn([]), do: {0,0,0} 
  defp get_app_vsn([{_app, _desc, vsn}]) do
    [maj, min, rev] = vsn
                      |> List.to_string
                      |> String.split(".")
                      |> Enum.map(&String.to_integer/1)
    {maj, min, rev}
  end
end
```

And then for usage:

```
iex(1)> AppHelper.app_version(:logger)
{1, 0, 5}
```

As always, there's probably a better way.

Comment: Good answer cheers. Though kinda a shame if that is the best way to get at it.

Comment: That's the guidance that Jose Valim gave to someone just a few weeks ago.  That is, use :application.which_application.  https://groups.google.com/d/msg/elixir-lang-talk/qlX4hJKZvC8/pCZBqM1zCQAJ

Answer (score 3):

You can simple use:

```
YourApp.Mixfile.project[:version]
```

Comment: Just FYI, that's a canned comment inserted automatically during review - it really doesn't reflect this case, which is unfortunate. My own take on it: An answer is a _statement_, ideally backed up with authoritative references, examples, and/or experiences. Although there is no question mark here, "What about..." is a _question_. If this is indeed an answer, I suggest you edit it to sound like one, and offer a brief explanation that would educate readers by connecting the proffered solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`Application.spec(:my_app, :vsn)` works when the application is started. If you're in a Mix task and you don't need to start the application, in Elixir 1.8 you can use:

```
MyApp.MixProject.project |> Keyword.fetch!(:version)
```