# Get version defined in mix.exs from a release build

Tags: phoenix-framework

Is there any way to get the version number(1.2.3, the following case) in release build? The package is build in distillery.

```
  def project do
    [app: :sample,
     version: "1.2.3",
     elixir: "~> 1.3",
     elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env),
     compilers: [:phoenix, :gettext] ++ Mix.compilers,
     build_embedded: (Mix.env == :stg) or (Mix.env == :prod),
     start_permanent: (Mix.env == :stg) or (Mix.env == :prod),
     aliases: aliases,
     deps: deps]
  end
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Another StackOverflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968253/access-project-version-within-elixir-application)

Comment: Thank you, that's just what I wanted :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access project version within elixir application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968253/access-project-version-within-elixir-application)