# Get elixir mix release version in application

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I have the following mix.exs

```
defmodule App.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  @version "0.1.0"
  def git_ref(), do: System.get_git_hash()

  def project do
    [
      app: :app,
      version: @version,
      ...
      releases: [
        app: fn ->
          [version: @version <> "+" <> git_ref()]
        end
      ]
    ]
  end
end
```

I would like to output the *release* version in my app. I have seen this question, [Access project version within elixir application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968253/access-project-version-within-elixir-application) but all the answers return "0.1.0", i.e the "project.version"

If I run my release with `_build/../app version`, it returns the correct value, so it is able to get the git hash and set the key value, but that value is written out to a file for the `version` command.

I just don't know how to get it "at runtime". Is this possible? I thought the version may overwrite the previous key value, but I guess they are distinct?

Comment: `@version "0.1.0" <> System.get_git_hash()`?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking

Comment: I’m suggesting a way to fix it. Just define `@version` as I showed above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the release version is not included into the beam files, it's purely metadata that's handled by the release scripts. I don't believe there is a built-in way to lookup the release version. However, the script [exports the version to `RELEASE_VSN`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.11/lib/mix/lib/mix/tasks/release.init.ex#L91), so you can use that.

```
System.get_env("RELEASE_VSN")
```

This is documented in the [Environment variables](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Release.html#module-environment-variables) section of the `mix release` docs:

> - `RELEASE_VSN` - the version of the release, otherwise the latest version is used. It can be set to a custom value when invoking the
>   release. The custom value must be an existing release version in the
>   `releases/` directory

Comment: Felt this may be the case.